# How to apply a Gradle plugin to the root project only?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I wrote a Gradle plugin that automatically update our microservices' versions when we do a pull request in Bitbucket, and it works well. It just updates a `version=x.y.z` key/value pair in the `gradle.properties` file.

However, I only want to apply it to the root project. How do I do that? Right now I have this in my `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: UpdaeVersionPlugin
}
```

I've tried `project`, `root`, `rootProject`, `rootproject`, etc instead of `allprojects`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apply external Plugin to a subset of subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087903/apply-external-plugin-to-a-subset-of-subprojects) did not directly answer my question, but it did contain the syntax I was looking for. It's

```
gradle.rootProject {
    apply plugin: UpdaeVersionPlugin
}
```